# Pushing new object and popping the first object of an Array of Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create an array of object with always length five, so first push five objects, when the length of an array reach five then pop the first object and push the new object on the same array. And this operation will continue in a certain interval(On interval of 5 Sec).

```
var arr = [{
        name: 'ABC', // Pop the first object when new object is push ..
    }, {
        name: 'ABC',
    }, {
        name: 'ABC',
    }, {
        name: 'ABC',
    }, {
        name: 'ABC',
}];

arr.push({ name: 'ABCNew'});
```

Is this possible? Guys, pls guide me on how to achieve this functionality?

I would appreciate the help, Many thanks!

Comment: [`Array.prototype.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

Comment: All you have to do is to call `arr.shift();` before or after pushing the new element. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
const add = (arr, ele) => [ele, ...arr].slice(0,5);

console.log(add([1,2,3], 6))
console.log(add([1,2,3,4,5], 6))
console.log(add([{ name: 'ABC' }, { name: 'ABC', }, { name: 'ABC', }, { name: 'ABC', }, { name: 'ABC', }], { name: 'ABCNew'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need a function which can check the length of an array and pushes and removes the object based on the length

```
var arr = [];
function pusher(obj){
   arr.push(obj);
   if(arr.length > 5){
       arr.shift();
   }
}
```

Comment: This what that actually I'm looking, thanks for the answer